# Why I cannot open Google or YouTube

Tags: wireless-networking, google-chrome, windows-8.1, dns, youtube

My PC suddenly cannot open www.google.com.  The error message is

> This site can’t be reached
>   **www.google.com** took too long to respond.

[image: screen shot of error message]

YouTube can only load homepage.  No videos can be opened. 
Nothing happens when I click on the videos.

The system is Windows 8.1.

- All browsers have same problem.
- I tried rebooting.
- Same thing happens even in clean boot mode.
- My iPhone works well with same Wi-Fi at my home.
- Have tried changing DNS and flushing DNS, but didn't work.

The problem exists even with cable connection. 
I am able to use Gmail, but not Google Maps, etc. 
I cannot see the CAPTCHA image in some websites. 
Can anyone help?

Comment: Have yoy rebooted your router? If so and the problem exists it may be ISP related - and google were.having issue earlier.today/yesterday so this could be related. Can you show the result of a traceroute?

Comment: https://www.cbsnews.com/news/google-cloud-outage-hits-youtube-gmail-snapchat-apps-services-today-2019-06-02-live-updates/

Comment: trace route on my pc is 216.58.200.23. on my iphone is (2607:f8b0:4005:804::2004)

Answer (score 1):

1. ping the site whether it can be reached or not
2. check for driver update is required or roll back to previous version.
3. Access the Safe Mode with Networking option if its works fine in safe mode then driver is the problem .

Comment: I pinged. It said request time out. The driver is up to date. I tried safe mode, it didn't work.

Comment: source :https://support.google.com/websearch/forum/AAAAgtjJeM4vZHCm-fXLxI/?hl=en&gpf=%23!msg%2Fwebsearch%2FvZHCm-fXLxI%2FouVCG7zcDAAJ&msgid=ouVCG7zcDAAJ.

 try the below steps to release the Google IP:
Go to Start on your windows system> Run > then type: %temp% again, try deleting everything > Restart your PC, 
Again go to Start > Run and type CMD, then select OK.
Type ipconfig /release and press Enter.
Once the prompt returns, type ipconfig /renew, then hit Enter.
Finally, type exit, then press Enter to close the window.
Restart and check again.

Comment: tried, not working. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

First please check whether the device time and date is correctly set.

---

If not so then it must be a problem of dns look up failed.

Set up the [cloudfare's 1.1.1.1](https://developers.cloudflare.com/1.1.1.1/setting-up-1.1.1.1/windows/) (it worked well for me).

Comment: the date and time is correct, same as my phone. I tried the 1.1.1.1, it didn't help. I have tried 8.8.8.8 before, it didn't help either.

Comment: could you please attach a screen shot of your problem. you can use the snipping tool to do so

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XH2zf.png

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working in iphone so surely its not ISP or router issue

All other sites are working on the same PC so not a driver issue

check the entries in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file.

trace route both devices using the following link
https://www.wikihow.com/Find-a-Website%27s-IP-Address

Comment: I have checked host file before. It seems ok. trace route on my pc is 216.58.200.23. on my iphone is (2607:f8b0:4005:804::2004).

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Your iphone is using ipv6, your PC is using IPV4 which is a totally different routing protocol.

Comment: I type the ipv4 address in my phone, it works. Does this mean the problem is in my PC?